# When I use the method from composable twice, it works weird

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I created a composable as follows to attach a header whenever I use the useFetch function.

```
export const useCommon = () => {
    async function useFetchToken(api: string, option: useFetchTokenTyle){
        const autoOption:any = {
            headers: (option.headers) ?? { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ado_token.value }
        }
        ...
        return await useFetch(api, {...option,...autoOption})   
    }
    return {
        useFetchToken
    }
}
```

and I use this useFetchToken composable twice in one

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const { useFetchToken } = useCommon()
let {data:category_lists, refresh:cateRefresh} = await useFetchToken('/api/action', { 
    baseURL: CATEGORY_API,
    method: 'post',
    body: {
        action: 'DoSomeThing',
    }
})

let {data:section_lists, refresh:sectionRefresh} = await useFetchToken('/api/action', { 
    baseURL: CATEGORY_API,
    method: 'post',
    body: {
        action: 'DoSomeThing2',
    }
})
```

Then, a strange result occurs.

"category_lists" affect from second useFetchToken composable.
"category_lists" is overwritten by 2nd  useFetchToken composable.

When I delete 2nd useFetchToken part, "category_lists" work correctly.
When I change useFetchToken to useFetch, it will work well all.

Comment: Composables returns useFetchToken function itself.

Comment: Oh, I understand a bit that my function is a closure. But I don't understand why it is giving me an error. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Now, please don't use stack overflow as your personal diary. Post a question you need to answer, not a question you know to answer, and with a typo every one can encounter and fix.

Comment: Please look at the body, action property. the 2 fetchs are return different result.